# Hi, I want help on making xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to take some help related to xpath.

Here is my html i want to make a xpath .

I need data in base of Product type and Max loan size

"Product Type" data is ->   2-year fixed rate until 30 April 2022

"Max loan size" data is -> £10m

I need a xpath that pick data according to  section from 
as i have mention above i need Product type data and Max loan size data and initial interest data.
from tbody .

```html
<table aria-label="Fixed-rate mortgage" data-component-type="Table" class="table table-sortable table-join   table-default table-responsive" data-filtering-enabled="false">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>
               <div class="aem-rte ">
                    <p>Product type</p>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="aem-rte ">
                    <p>Max loan size</p>
                </div>
            </th>
            <th>
                <div class="aem-rte ">
                    <p>Initial interest
                        <br />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </th>
         
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div class="aem-rte ">
                        <p>2-year fixed rate until 30 April 2022</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div class="aem-rte ">
                        <p>£10m</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div class="aem-rte ">
                       <p>2.09%</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What would look like your desired outcome?

Comment: Thanks for answer . really appreciated. I need that xpath which take data with respect of <thead> e.g Product Type . If we take by defining index this will be work on some cases. There are multiple table and multiple <tbody> values . For example if we give INdex [1] for product Type value . on some case if it will on index 2, or 3 so it will  give us wrong data . Current situation Product Type value is exists on index 1. but on some case its exists on index 2 and on some its not exists . i hope you will understand now . so what i do on those cases...

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression:

```
//tbody/tr/td/div/div[@class='aem-rte ']/p[1]
```

If you used XPath-2.0, you could also make use of the `fn:string-join` function to create a delimited string like this:

```
string-join(//tbody/tr/td/div/div[@class='aem-rte ']/p[1],' - ')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//tbody//tr[1]//td[1]/div[1]/p
//tbody//tr[2]//td[2]/div[1]/p
```

or

```
//p[contains(text(),'2-year fixed rate until 30 April 2022')]

//p[contains(text(),'£10m')]
```

Comment: I need a xpath that get data according to "Product type" . something like following sibling. Because if data in tbody will change position then it will give me wrong value . It is only possible if  we make an xpath related to <thead>  like product type , max loan size